# How can I get a percentage breakdown of individual ethnicity variables from a question that allowed subjects to select multiple responses?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I ran this code to get the breakdown of ethnicities in my sample:

```
dataset %>% 

group_by(ethnicity) %>%
  summarise(percent = 100 * n()/nrow(datset))
```

However, because subjects were able to select multiple ethnicity categories on their questionnaire, the results came out like this:

```
 1 "[\"Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander\",\"Caucasian\",\"Asian (inc. Indian subcontinent)\"]"  0.364 
 2 "[\"Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander\",\"Caucasian\"]"                                       0.0910
 3 "[\"Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander\"]"                                                     0.910 
 4 "[\"African\"]"                                                                                  0.637 
 5 "[\"Asian (inc. Indian subcontinent)\"]"                                                                     0.0910
 9 "[\"Caucasian\",\"Latino/Hispanic\"]"                                                            0.182 
10 "[\"Caucasian\",\"Middle Eastern\"]"                                                             0.273 
11 "[\"Caucasian\",\"Not listed\"]"                                                                 0.182
```

etc.

What would be the best/most efficient way to get a breakdown of the individual (non-combined) categories?

I basically just want a percentage breakdown of:

```
Caucausian  - 
African -
Latino/Hispanic -
Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander -
Middle Eastern -
```

Etc.

Comment: FYI you should use a tag specific to the code you're writing. [tag:recode] and [tag:categories] seem very generic. Also, this seems like more of an opinion-based / broad question, not a specific programming question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. You just swapped one set of generic tags for another ([tag:group-by] doesn't help). What, exactly, is your code written in? What language is `dataset %>% `? Also, you still haven't given any detail about what specific issue you're having. Please read [ask] as well as how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- data.frame(id = c(1:5, 9:11),
  eth = c("[\"Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander\",\"Caucasian\",\"Asian (inc. Indian subcontinent)\"]",
"[\"Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander\",\"Caucasian\"]"                                      ,
"[\"Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander\"]"                                                    ,
"[\"African\"]"                                                                                 ,
"[\"Asian (inc. Indian subcontinent)\"]"                                                        ,
"[\"Caucasian\",\"Latino/Hispanic\"]"                                                           ,
 "[\"Caucasian\",\"Middle Eastern\"]"                                                           ,
 "[\"Caucasian\",\"Not listed\"]"                   )
)

mydf |> 
  separate_longer_delim(eth, ",") |> 
  mutate(eth = str_remove_all(eth, '"|\\[|\\]')) |> 
  count(eth) |> 
  mutate(pct = n / nrow(mydf)) |> 
  arrange(desc(pct))
    
                                   eth n   pct
1                            Caucasian 5 0.625
2 Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander 3 0.375
3     Asian (inc. Indian subcontinent) 2 0.250
4                              African 1 0.125
5                      Latino/Hispanic 1 0.125
6                       Middle Eastern 1 0.125
7                           Not listed 1 0.125
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset |> 
  mutate(ethnicity = str_remove_all(ethnicity, "\\\\|\\[|\\]|\"") |> str_split(",")) |>
  unnest(ethnicity) |> 
  summarise(pct = n() / nrow(dataset) * 100, .by = ethnicity)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  ethnicity                              pct
  <chr>                                <dbl>
1 Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander  37.5
2 Caucasian                             62.5
3 Asian (inc. Indian subcontinent)      25  
4 African                               12.5
5 Latino/Hispanic                       12.5
6 Middle Eastern                        12.5
7 Not listed                            12.5
```

Data:

```
dataset <- data.frame(
  ethnicity = c(
    '["Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander","Caucasian","Asian (inc. Indian subcontinent)"]',
    '["Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander","Caucasian"]',
    '["Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander"]',
    '["African"]',
    '["Asian (inc. Indian subcontinent)"]',
    '["Caucasian","Latino/Hispanic"]',
    '["Caucasian","Middle Eastern"]',
    '["Caucasian","Not listed"]'
  )
)
```